# Environment partially in english on a french Ubuntu14.04 version

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, language-support

For an unknown reason a part of my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS French version has moved to English, specifically commands like "Show copy Dialog" in Nautilus.

I've double checked that languages packages are properly installed in Ubuntu parameters and they are.

Any idea ?

Laurent06000

PS 1: as asked I had the results of land printenv

locale -a gives

> locale -a
>   C
>   C.UTF-8
>   en_AG
>   en_AG.utf8
>   en_AU.utf8
>   en_BW.utf8
>   en_CA.utf8
>   en_DK.utf8
>   en_GB.utf8
>   en_HK.utf8
>   en_IE.utf8
>   en_IN
>   en_IN.utf8
>   en_NG
>   en_NG.utf8
>   en_NZ.utf8
>   en_PH.utf8
>   en_SG.utf8
>   en_US.utf8
>   en_ZA.utf8
>   en_ZM
>   en_ZM.utf8
>   en_ZW.utf8
>   fr_BE.utf8
>   fr_CA.utf8
>   fr_CH.utf8
>   fr_FR.utf8
>   fr_LU.utf8
>   POSIX
>
> printenv gives :
>
> printenv
>   XDG_VTNR=7
>   XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
>   CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
>   SELINUX_INIT=YES
>   XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/laurent06000
>   SESSION=ubuntu
>   GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-NBoFPL/gpg:0:1
>   SHELL=/bin/bash
>   XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
>   VTE_VERSION=3409
>   TERM=xterm
>   WINDOWID=106954764
>   UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1206
>   GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-NBoFPL
>   GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
>   USER=laurent06000
>   LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
>   XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
>   XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-NBoFPL/ssh
>   SESSION_MANAGER=local/PC-DE-LDP:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1373,unix/PC-DE-LDP:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1373
>   DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
>   XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
>   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>   DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
>   QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
>   QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
>   JOB=dbus
>   PWD=/home/laurent06000
>   XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
>   GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
>   LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   GDM_LANG=fr_FR
>   MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
>   IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
>   COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
>   GDMSESSION=ubuntu
>   SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
>   XDG_SEAT=seat0
>   HOME=/home/laurent06000
>   SHLVL=1
>   LANGUAGE=fr_FR
>   GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
>   LOGNAME=laurent06000
>   XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
>   QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dXIW7UzRJs
>   LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
>   INSTANCE=
>   TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
>   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>   DISPLAY=:0
>   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
>   GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
>   LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
>   TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
>   COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
>   XAUTHORITY=/home/laurent06000/.Xauthority
>   _=/usr/bin/printenv

Comment: Add results for `locale -a` to the question please. And these https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables will help too.

Comment: Also please show us the output of the `locale` command (without options).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just occasional strings which appear in English, the explanation may simply be that those particular strings were not translated into French in 14.04.

Comment: Not at all sorry Gunnar, the translation was correct some days ago and I didn't anything else than maintaining my 14.04 LTS up to date if asked tu install updates...